# Unhandled exception in botan.dll

Tags: c++, exception, dll, botan

I am trying to run the most basic program with botan crypto library. I am using Botan 1.10 32bit. I got the binaries with their installer on Windows 7. IDE is Visual studio 2012.

I linked my project to botan.lib but the program reports a missing botan.dll on startup so I assume that the lib just links to the dll. Therefore I've put the botan.dll in the Debug folder.

Now to the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <botan/botan.h>
using namespace Botan;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        cout << "d1";
        LibraryInitializer init;  //exception thrown here
    }
    catch(exception& e) {
        cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    cout << "d2";
    return 0;
}
```

Intellisense detects everything ok. When I try to debug, I get:

> First-chance exception at 0x6A1F2AA0 (botan.dll) in rsa.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00310000. Unhandled
>   exception at 0x6A1F2AA0 (botan.dll) in rsa.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00310000.

It seems that an exception is thrown inside botan.dll and I can't catch it on my side. I cannot go further from here.

Did I do something wrong linking to the library or is there some other problem? Help appreciated.

Comment: I do not know botan. But from the error I see it looks like botan.dll is trying to use some dlls. Does it come as a single dll, or as a package? If there are other dlls, or config/ini files, you may need to copy them as well. The simplest way in this case will be to add a path to botan folder in your PATH Environment Variable. Have you tried to use Dependency Walker on botan.dll?

Comment: I updated my PATH and copied everything from botan directory but nothing changed. There is just a .lib, .dll and .exp.

Comment: what kind of dll is it? is it a COM dll? But I guess it is a normal dll, as it has a lib file. Have you tried to open it with dependency walker. It usually reports straight away if a dependent dll is missing. Are you building a 32 or 64 bit application?

Comment: I am building for Win32. Dependency-walker reports 10 modules missing and 10 missing an export function for parent. How do I actually determine whether any of these are actually the problem? Here is the list of them: http://pastebin.com/wER4a9TH

Comment: looks like botan is not supported in Windows 8. Contact the vendor to have the version for Windows 8 supplied for you

Comment: Does it crash with a release build of your program as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

If your program crashes even with a release build of your program, you'll have to download the source and build it yourself (python is required to configure the build).

In case the release build does not crash, you can disable the `/RTCs Stack Frames` runtime check in your `C++/Code Generation` project settings for your debug build, which appears to be causing the crash. Simply change the setting from `Both` to `/RTCu Uninitialized Variables` 
or disable it altogether by setting it to `Default`.

Since this is a workaround and not a solution, you should consider building botan yourself and build both release and debug versions (then you can link to the debug version in
your debug build and leave the debug runtime checks as they are.

Refer to the [documentation](http://botan.randombit.net/building.html) on how to build it (you'll need [python](http://www.python.org/) to run the configuration):

Once you built the release version (default), copy the following files to another directory (for example `C:\Botan\release\`) or they will be overwritten when you build the debug version:

- botan.dll
- botan.exp
- botan.lib
- botan.dll.manifest

Now run configure again, this time add the `--enable-debug` option:

```
> python configure.py --cc=msvc --enable-debug
```

and build it again. This time, copy the files (listed above) to `C:\Botan\debug\`.

Configure your project to link to the library in the debug directory for debug builds and the one in the release directory for release builds.
Finally make sure that your program loads the appropriate DLL when you run it.

Comment: I did all the steps above and managed to make it work with vs2010. I still got the exact same error even after first build but after the second build it dissapeared. I am not sure exactly why but I will probably approve your answer unless I run into something weird in the next day.

Comment: I will also try to build with vs2012 again just to make sure it actually can't build or I did something wrong.

Comment: @cen build the self-test executable `nmake check` after building Botan and run it (`check.exe`). If **that** one crashes, you may have to wait for a future release. If you look at the [build log](http://botan.randombit.net/build_log.html) Botan is not tested on VC2012. VC2010 (version 16.00.30319.01) is the highest one tested. However, if `check.exe` **does** work, double check if your program is finding (and loading) the proper DLL (the one built with the same compiler you use for your program and the DLL from the debug step for the program built with debug).

Comment: All tests pass for vs2010. vs2012 on the other hand does not even compile.

Comment: @cen it's a long shot, but did you try the debug DLL built with VC2010 with the debug version of your program built in 2012? or disable all runtime checks in 2012 when building your program as debug? Also what sort of compiler errors do you get with 2012?

Answer (score 0):

The binaries you are using are probably aimed for release mode. I tried linking in debug mode and got access violation too, then I switched to release mode and everything worked fine. I'm also not sure if the binaries are aiming VC110. You could download the source and try to build it with your preferable configurations.

Comment: I am using Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012 (vc 110 platform tool set).

Comment: Not even release worked for me. I will report back here in near future if I manage to build from source with vs2012 and use it tho.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is Windows you will not ever see a C++ exception cross a module boundary. Consequently your attempt to catch a C++ exception will fail to recognize this one. If you want to get your hands on an access violation you will need to use [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657.aspx) instead.

To find out why the .dll is crashing you should set up Visual Studio to break into the debugger when an access violation is generated. Go to *Debug* -> *Exceptions* and tick the *Thrown* checkbox for *c0000005 Access violation* under *Win32 Exceptions*. Once in the debugger you can load the debugging symbols (assuming they are available). The call stack and parameters should give you a fairly good idea of why it is failing.

Since the source seems to be available you could also compile a Debug .dll yourself. This would both produce proper debugging symbols as well as enable source level debugging of the crash. This is likely to give you all the information you need to diagnose the issue at hand.